# hide and show multiple div with multiple checkbox

Tags: jquery, html

I have several checkboxes as determinants for availability of div.

It works when I added jquery 
But, the problem is when I clicked `chk1` and unchecked it, I want third `p` still appear because third `p` contain class `sb2`. Any suggest for what I should to changes?

```js
$('.sb').hide();
var first = true;

$('input[type="checkbox"][name^=chk]').change(function() {
  var $target = $('.sb' + this.id.replace('chk', '')).toggle(this.checked);
  if (first) {
    $('p[class^=sb]').not($target).hide();
    first = false;
  }
}).change()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="sb sb1">Checkbox content one</p>
<p class="sb sb2">Checkbox content two</p>
<p class="sb sb1 sb2">Checkbox content one & two</p>
<input name="chk1" type="checkbox" id="chk1" value="">chekme1
<input name="chk2" type="checkbox" id="chk2" value="" checked>checkme2
```

Answer (score 0):

Just trigger it

```js
$('.sb').hide();
var first = true;

$('input[type="checkbox"][name^=chk]').change(function() {
  var $target = $('.sb' + this.id.replace('chk', '')).toggle(this.checked);
  if (first) {
    $('p[class^=sb]').not($target).hide();
    first = false;
  }
}).change()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="sb sb1">Checkbox content one</p>
<p class="sb sb2">Checkbox content two</p>
<p class="">Checkbox content one & two</p>
<input name="chk1" type="checkbox" id="chk1" value="">chekme1
<input name="chk2" type="checkbox" id="chk2" value="" checked>checkme2
```

Comment: Sorry, I changed my code in my question. When I click 'checkme1' and then unchecked it, I want `Checkbox content one & two` still appear

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. My code should do what you need

Comment: I changed p class `sb sb3` to `sb sb1 sb2`

Comment: So remove sb* from the third p - your change does not make sense to the script that runs

Comment: Please update your question with expected behaviour. What is shown when 1 is checked when 2 is checked when either is unchecked